Quasiparticles in maxwell-boltzmann distribution
Please refer to this paper Quasiparticles, flat bands and the melting of hydrodynamic matter by Imran Saeed, Hyuk Kyu Pak and Tsvi Tlusty.
According to this paper, quasiparticle phenomena have been observed in the macroscopic world.
It is said that colloidal particles combine with each other to form pairs and move like one particle, which can even be observed with the naked eye.
They also explain that it moves with hydrodynamic forces, so should this be interpreted as a macroscopic particle? Or should it be viewed as a quantum mechanical particle?
I expect that if the particles described in this paper are quantum mechanical particles, they will follow the Bose-Einstein distribution, and if they are classical particles, they will follow the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution.
In conclusion, what are the classical conditions for particles that follow the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution?

The paper explicitly states that they are studying "a classical system of hydrodynamically interacting particles in two dimensions". [2] The particles interact through hydrodynamic forces which are classical in nature.
They can be observed with the naked eye, which indicates they are operating at a macroscopic scale, far larger than the quantum realm.[1]
The authors make parallels with other classical systems, using the phrase "classical analog" of quantum phenomena observed in materials like graphene.[1]
Using the phrase "classical analog" of quantum phenomena observed in materials like graphene, the authors are making parallels with other classical systems.[1]
As the particles are classical and macroscopic, the distribution follows the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution not the Bose-Einstein distribution.
As classical particles, they would be expected to follow the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution and not the Bose-Einstein distribution.
The colloidal particles form pairs owing to hydrodynamic interactions, that mimics some aspects of quantum quasiparticles but, the underlying physics remains classical. [1][2].
Citations:
[1] https://phys.org/news/2023-01-scientists-quasiparticles-classical.html
[2] https://www.nature.com/articles/s41567-022-01893-5

Thank you so much. Let me ask you one more question. Is the colloidal particle used in this study a particle that represents a quasiparticle phenomenon, not a quasiparticle?

No. collectively their behavior exhibits some properties analogous to quasiparticles in quantum systems. But the interesting thing is that some concepts from quantum matter physics might apply to classical settings, in certain conditions.
